# Как решить проблему "This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners that can run this job"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Мне нужно настроить деплой проекта на сервер через ssh. Сгенерировал ssh key и написа следующий скрипт .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: java:8

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - chmod +x mvnw

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./mvnw package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
        ssh -i $IDENTITY user@server
        scp -r target/admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war user@server:opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments
  only:
    - master
```

gitlab требует создать runner
This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners that can run this job. Go to Runners page

В секции настроек несколько видов, как и какой нужно создать?

Comment: Устанавливаете gitlab-runner. выполняете `sudo gitlab-runner register`, следуете инструкциям (инфу брать из настроек проекта в секции CI/CD). Выполняете `sudo gitlab-runner start`. Наслаждаетесь. Gitlab-runner можно установить на другой сервер. Ибо сборка может отжирать много ресурсов

Answer (score 0):

Тоже когда начал настраивать, было такое сообшение. Следовал оригинальному мануалу и всё заработало:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/.

Необходомо установить, настроить, зарегистрировать и запустить `git-runner`.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/508290)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica А что является самым главным? Добавить пару команд из мануала, как в комментарии под вопросом, это явно недостаточно. Скопировать сюда весь мануал, будет явный перебор.